# Debug docker script more efficiently

Tags: docker

I'm getting started on my first docker script and i'm trying to debug the last step and it's very slow debugging b/c the steps before it take a few minutes to run so if i have a typo, i have to re run the entire script.

Is there a more efficient way to debug a docker script? or do i have to rebuild the whole thing every time?

```
#FROM ubuntu:14.04
FROM node:0.10.40
#FROM mongo:2.6.11

# The port we're running the server on
EXPOSE 10645

# Set this as the working directory
WORKDIR /myproject/hapi

# Move the myproject files to /myproject in the docker container
ADD . /myproject/hapi

# Install the server dependencies
RUN pwd && ls -al && npm install

# Start everything up
CMD npm start
```

Log output:

```
^CR5033505:myproject m089269$ docker build -t myproject-hapi .
Sending build context to Docker daemon 932.2 MB
Step 0 : FROM node:0.10.40
 ---> a7d8016a6fdb
Step 1 : EXPOSE 10645
 ---> Running in ebc4f8ebbf7b
 ---> 701320586e6a
Removing intermediate container ebc4f8ebbf7b
Step 2 : WORKDIR /myproject/hapi
 ---> Running in 1998f97b252a
 ---> 1414baf38920
Removing intermediate container 1998f97b252a
Step 3 : ADD . /myproject/hapi
 ---> c80e665da20b
Removing intermediate container f6904fab79ce
Step 4 : RUN pwd && ls -al && npm install
 ---> Running in a3ef28ed70ae
/myproject/hapi
total 68
drwxr-xr-x  9 root root 4096 Oct 30 18:35 .
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Oct 30 18:35 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  509 Apr 10  2015 .editorconfig
drwxr-xr-x  8 root root 4096 Oct 30 18:33 .git
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  491 Oct 20 15:09 .gitignore
drwxr-xr-x  8 root root 4096 Aug 19 14:51 .idea
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1781 Apr 10  2015 .jscsrc
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 6164 Apr 10  2015 .tfignore
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  430 Oct 30 18:33 Dockerfile
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  371 Oct 30 18:16 Dockerfile-client
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 1374 Oct 30 15:15 README.md
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root 4096 Oct 21 21:18 ab-testing-deploy
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Oct 30 15:15 build
drwxr-xr-x 14 root root 4096 Oct 30 15:15 client
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Apr 10  2015 githooks
drwxr-xr-x 10 root root 4096 Oct 30 15:15 hapi
npm ERR! install Couldn't read dependencies
npm ERR! Linux 4.1.10-boot2docker
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v0.10.40
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.1
npm ERR! path /myproject/hapi/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOPACKAGEJSON
npm ERR! errno 34

npm ERR! package.json ENOENT, open '/myproject/hapi/package.json'
npm ERR! package.json This is most likely not a problem with npm itself.
npm ERR! package.json npm can't find a package.json file in your current directory.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /myproject/hapi/npm-debug.log
The command '/bin/sh -c pwd && ls -al && npm install' returned a non-zero code: 34
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately when you're doing your `ADD` command you're invalidating the docker build cache, so any commands after that will be run from scratch.  From the docs:

> Note: The first encountered ADD instruction will invalidate the cache for all following instructions from the Dockerfile if the contents of  have changed. This includes invalidating the cache for RUN instructions.
>
> https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#add

I think in this case it would be easiest to run an interactive container and run each command from your `Dockerfile` one by one so you can see which one fails and be in a position to run it again immediately after you attempt to fix the error.

For example:

```
docker run -ti -v /path/to/your/code:/myproject/hapi node:0.10.40 bash

$ cd /myproject/hapi
$ npm install
```

Then when you do an `ls -la` you'll be able to see that `package.json` either isn't there or something else is wrong, and once you've figured it out you can add that command into your `Dockerfile`.

Comment: You can actually start from any layer as well, you don't have to start from the base image. So using your example output , the line `---> c80e665da20b` means the layer `c80e665da20b` was succesful, you can run from that layer using: `docker run -ti c80e665da20b bash`, and then do the next step manually until it works.

Comment: Once you have it working , you can also re-arrange your `Dockerfile` and only `ADD` the files that list the dependency (`package.json`), then run `npm install`, and `ADD . /myproject/hapi`at the very end. That way you'll only have to wait on the `npm install` step when your dependencies change, not on any code change.

Comment: @dnephin nice! I didn't know you could do that.